# how can i to do cross-page posting?that better?

Tags: asp.net

The project uses the "cross-page posting" (p.s. 1) . but that changed form one-way web page to two-way transfer value. Each time have to convert to type of program on the previous page is.
The programming will become too long, and the maintenance people will also see pain (maintenance is also me);
I want to ask how to code the program?that better? Thank you.

```
 If TypeOf Me.PreviousPage Is PP001 Then
                ID = DirectCast(Me.PreviousPage, PP001).ID
            ElseIf TypeOf Me.PreviousPage Is PM002 Then
                ID = DirectCast(Me.PreviousPage, PP002).ID
            ElseIf TypeOf Me.PreviousPage Is PM003 Then
                ID = DirectCast(Me.PreviousPage, PP003).ID
            ElseIf TypeOf Me.PreviousPage Is PP004 Then
                ID = DirectCast(Me.PreviousPage, PP004).ID
            ElseIf TypeOf Me.PreviousPage Is PP005 Then
                ID = DirectCast(Me.PreviousPage, PP005).ID
            ElseIf TypeOf Me.PreviousPage Is PP006 Then
                ID = DirectCast(Me.PreviousPage, PP006).ID
            ElseIf TypeOf Me.PreviousPage Is PP007 Then
                ID = DirectCast(Me.PreviousPage, PP007).ID
            ElseIf TypeOf Me.PreviousPage Is PP008 Then
                ID = DirectCast(Me.PreviousPage, PP008).ID
            ElseIf TypeOf Me.PreviousPage Is PP009 Then
                ID = DirectCast(Me.PreviousPage, PP009).ID
            End If
```

p.s.1:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/ms178139(v=vs.100)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

p.s.2:The 'ID' is property,not webcontrol.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to get the `ID` value using reflection. Try below.

`ID = Me.PreviousPage.GetType().GetProperty("ID").GetValue(Me.PreviousPage, null)`

Comment: Hi Aditya Bhave:
    Thank you so much!!!!!  I need this!!! Is very short and clear!!!! just one line!
And it did work! thank you!

Comment: Happy to help :)